# Simulating flipping live tiles in html

Tags: jquery, html, microsoft-metro, tiles

I need to code some html square "live tiles" that flip between 4 states periodically. 
Basically what I need is what this plug-in does http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs, but between 4 states, not just 2.
Is there a definitive API/plug-in that allows live tile management in html/jquery sites?
I'm not building a Windows 8 app, I'm just trying to simulate Live Tiles flipping in Html, and hopefully have it work in all major browsers.
Thanks.

Comment: Drew's plug-in only supports tiles with 2 states, front and back. I need it to support 4 states or more per tile. And customizing it to work like that might take a lot of time for someone with not much experience in jquery

Comment: Actually it does support multiple states. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

In the end, it seems that [Drew's plug-in](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs) does support multiple tile states, he provided a couple of samples. [Sample 1](http://jsfiddle.net/drewgreenwell/9w98S/) and [Sample 2](http://jsfiddle.net/drewgreenwell/xQUrK/). It seems to do what I need for live tile simulation.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm just trying to simulate Live Tiles flipping in Html, and
>   hopefully have it work in all major browsers

I think this is what you need. **Flip! http://lab.smashup.it/flip/**

Answer (score 1):

You might consider reading this article (below) on how to do flips with CSS3/HTML5 transitions.  It's not Javascript (and thus doesn't have an API), but in my experience transition effects seem to be a little more reliable in their smoothness.

[Animated Element Wall With CSS](http://designshack.net/articles/css/build-an-animated-photo-wall-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy. Specifically:

- Create a DIV with your N tile-sized contents
- Clip it/size the parent div to 1 tile size
- Make sure that overflow is hidden.
- Apply translate's to the previous content & new content using CSS

Then everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a bit new to jquery, but this might be a quick solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery or jQuery UI to get this effect. jQuery has `.animate()`, `.show()`, `.hide()` and other methods that can help.

Comment: Thanks, I might just have to customize it like that. I was just wondering, since metro style apps and live tiles are becoming more and more common, if there was a plug-in/api that did this out of the box.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the jquery animations unless they've been switched to CSS3 transitions/animations. Running the animation in script will not allow it to run smoothly