# Make the child background fill the available space

Tags: html, css

After watching a tutorial I am trying to make a windows 8 like animation using css3. To show the problem I have set the background to red. I want to flip vertically the entire blue block instead of the text. I am asking only for top block.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code snippet for those red front and back:

```css
 .front, .back {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;

      position: relative;
      display:block;
      background-color:red;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

Here is the complete [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InsaneCoder/AZCMD/)

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: Are you looking for how to animate it growing, or just CSS to fill the area?

Comment: @css :See the edited question with the fiddle link.

Comment: @Jnatalzia:See the  jsfiddle link at the end.

Comment: @MilchePatern:I didn't get what you said?Can you please help with my problem.I am eagerly waiting for the solution from an hour

Comment: I was saying : you are not looking for debug help, you are looking for a developer who will do it for you. Oterwhise, just remove the RED from the .front, .back{background:red} and it will look like it's flipping.

Comment: @MilchePatern: am looking for debug help only.After Hours of trial I have now found that I need to make changes in `todos-thumb` but I need help as I can't proceed further.I am not that expert in CSS

Answer (score 1):

## Update 3

It looks like what you are trying to ask is **How to Mimic Windows 8 flip tiles using html, css, and javascript**.  I would recommend abstracting your question to focus on just those details instead of providing extra code.  It has already been asked on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782237/simulating-flipping-live-tiles-in-html).

Here are some additional resources:

- [Windows 8 Metro Tiles with HTML, CSS3 and JavaScript](http://ryanlowdermilk.com/2012/03/windows-8-metro-tiles-with-html-css3-and-javascript/)
- [Flip! A jQuery plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/)
- [Metro Tile - GitHub](https://github.com/ryanlowdermilk/metro-tile)
- [Design Shack Flip Tile](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/PhotoWall/flip.html)
- [Metro Live Tiles - Drew Greenwell](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs)

Try to implement these and ask a more focused question if you get stuck.

Here's a working sample the relevant code from your question

**HTML**

```html
<div class="demo-wrapper">
  <div class="dashboard clearfix">
      <div class="col1 clearfix flip-container vertical">
        <div class="big todos-thumb flipper" >
            <div class="front" >
                <p>My Todos</p>
            </div>
            <div class="back" >
                <p>You have 5 more tasks to do!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
/*rotate entire block on hover over middle */
.vertical.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
/*re-rotate inner background text back to normal*/
.vertical.flip-container:hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
/*normally hide back*/
.vertical.flip-container .back {
    display:none;
}
/*hide front on flip */
.vertical.flip-container:hover .front {
    display:none;
}
/*show back on flip*/
.vertical.flip-container:hover .back {
    display:block;
}
```

## See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/AZCMD/2/)

Comment: :See the fiddle link at the end

Comment: @InsaneCoder, is there some reason this isn't what you were looking for?

Comment: :Sir ,I want that the entire block flips.That is,when the block flips white background shows up and then the other side of the block is shown.Similar to windows phone screensaver.Actually I will later convert it into a lively widget,in which every blocks keeps flipping after certain duration.

Comment: Sir I would really appreciate if you help as I am frustrated with hit and trials .Its already 2'0 clock here and I won't be able to sleep until I solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your upper block to 'flip' you will have to 'rebuild' your html markup. You are actually asking (in code) to flip what's inside the blue box.

flip-container  and  flipper are your triggering classes.

Just ask (in code) to flip the blue box by adding your triggering classes to the right containers.

```
<div class="col1 clearfix flip-container vertical">
    <div class="big todos-thumb flipper">
        ...
```

and .. this has nothing to do with css.